# Switch Statement continue

Tags: c++, switch-statement

Is the following possible in C++?

```
switch (value) {
   case 0:
      // code statements
      break;
   case 1:
   case 2:
      // code statements for case 1 and case 2
      /**insert statement other than break here
       that makes the switch statement continue
       evaluating case statements rather than
       exit the switch**/
   case 2:
      // code statements specific for case 2
      break;
}
```

I want to know if there is a way to make the switch statement continue evaluating the rest of the cases even after it has hit a matching case. (such as a `continue` statement in other languages)

Comment: Why do you have `case 2` twice?

Comment: What do you mean by *scanning* the rest of the cases? `switch` works like a `goto`, and only stops falling through when it reaches a `break`

Comment: @andy256 I meant evaluating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about a simple `if`?

```
switch (value)
{
case 0:
    // ...
    break;

case 1:
case 2:
    // common code
    if (value == 2)
    {
        // code specific to "2"
    }
    break;

case 3:
    // ...
}
```

Comment: If the order of the common and the specific code doesn't matter, you can also do `case 2: { /* code specific to 2 */} case 1: { /* common code */ }`.

Answer (score 2):

Once the case label is decided, there is no way to have the `switch` continue to search for other matching labels. You can continue to process the code for the following label(s) but this doesn't distinguish between the different reasons why a `case` label was reached. So, no, there is no way to coninue the selection. In fact, duplicate `case` labels are prohibited in C++.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, just don't put in a break.  It will naturally fall down to the other switch statements.

Comment: Falling of the end of the `case 1: case 2:` labels would process the following statement for `value` being both `1` or `2`. The original question seems to be about processing the second `case 2:` label only when `value` is `2` and not when it is `1`.